# Mongoose isn't creating Collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I'm using **MongoDB v4.4** and **Mongoose v5.11.18**, when the code runs, it shows some warnings and google says they will be removed in the upcoming version.

[Warnings are,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovKvk.png)

Although the connection is established and I'm not able to see anything in the mongo shell.

Mongoose Section,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/fruit", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected");
  // we're connected!
});

let fruitScehma = mongoose.Schema({
  Name: String,
  rate: Number,
});

let friut = (module.exports = mongoose.model("fruit", fruitScehma));
```

Answer (score 0):

- This is how I always do mongoose connection

```js
export const connectDB = async () =>
{
    await mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    } );
};
```

- Then in your server.js

```js
const main = async () => {
   await connectDB();
   
   // app.listen....
}

main().catch(err => console.error(err));
```